# How to check if a View(Button, ImageView etc.) is clickable or not from Java code?

Tags: android, view

I am trying to count the all clickable views on a screen. I tried **view.isClickable()** method. But it doesn't work. I think maybe it works only on ViewGroup.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout rel;
        rel=findViewById(R.id.relative_my);
        int count=getChildrenViews(rel);
    }
    private int getChildrenViews(ViewGroup parent){
        int count = parent.getChildCount();
        View view=(View) parent;
        if(view.isClickable())
        {
            Log.v("Clickable","Yes"+ view.toString());
        }
        for (int i=0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
            if (parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup){
                count+=getChildrenViews((ViewGroup) parent.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

XML code is below:
It contains 2 Buttons and 2 ImageViews.I want to find out how to look for Clickable view like ImageView or Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative_my"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/book" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:text="Button1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="700dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Button2"/>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/book" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can put a "*clickable: true*" attribute in an XML Tag then you can use "isClickable()" on it. All classes descending from "View" are elegible to this behaviour.

Your code seems wrong because accepts only ViewGroups.

Try this:

```
private int getChildrenViews(@Nullable final View view) {
    if (view == null) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    if (view instanceof View) {
        count += ((View)view).isClickable() ? 1 : 0;
        Log.d("View", "clickable: " + view.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            count += getChildrenViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
        Log.d("ViewGroup", view.getClass().getSimpleName()" contains "+count +" clickable Views/ViewGroups");
    }
    return count;
}
```